# Microsoft Academic - calchistogram query to find citations by year

Tags: api, azure-cognitive-services

The [product page for Microsoft Academic Knowledge API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge/) mentions that it is possible to find out the distribution of citations by year for a given author using the calchistogram method:

> "Calculates a histogram of the distribution of attribute values for
>   the academic entities returned by a query expression, such as the
>   distribution of citations by year for a given author."

How does one actually perform such a query using the calchistogram method?

The [example in the API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge/calchistogrammethod) presents a way to find the distribution of papers by year

```
https:// westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/calchistogram?expr=And(Composite(AA.AuN=='jaime teevan'),Y>2012)&attributes=Y,F.FN&count=4
```

but it is not clear how to modify this to obtain citation counts.

Comment: Honestly I don't understand what you are looking for as everything is explained in the example of the API documentation that you quoted

Comment: I would like to know how to construct a calchistogram query to find out how many citations per year an author has received (cf. histograms in Google Scholar profiles, e.g. [https://scholar.google.fi/citations?user=F5Ik84MAAAAJ&hl=fi&oi=ao]). My understanding is that this is not possible with the current API, but I would be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: So you want to `generate a histogram of the count of publications by year for a particular author `, right?

Comment: No, I want to create a histogram of the **citations** by year for a particular author.

Comment: sorry... it was so obvious, thanks for the clarification

Comment: I tried several things but can't manage to "group by year" the citation count, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you like this, but here is a strawman approach:

evaluate Composite(AA.AuN=='jaime teevan')
return attributes: [Id,Ti,Y,CC,ECC]

to get ALL papers. each paper has [Year, Citation Count]

And then do the math.

What's bad? not elegant
What's not so bad? the # of papers published by an author is enumerable, not many.
What's good? one query serves all. [you can also get publication count histogram by doing this]